# How do I change the css gradient values when my progress bar value changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, progress

In my CSS file I have the following code (for Google Chrome) that styles the progress bar with a gradient effect.

```
progress[value] {
    width: 100%; height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 3em;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background-image:

    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,
                           transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 44%,
                           rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
                           rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
                           rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #04d647, #009999);
}
```

However my JavaScript code causes my progress bar to constantly change values. Right now the gradient color is set to a green gradient, but I would like to change the color based on how high the value is (i.e. less than 30% = red gradient, less than 65% but more than 30% = yellow gradient, and more than 65% = green gradient).

I have this JavaScript code to start off with in my HTML file, but I don't know how I would go about changing the colors in progress::-webkit-progress-value depending on what the value is, because I don't know how I would use the webkit-progress as a tag.

```
if (progressbar1.value >= .30) {

   $("progress::-webkit-progress-value").css("background-color", "#424242");
   // something like this^^....what tags/scripts go here??

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Someone answer my question :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a data attribute to your `progress` tag, which will hold the values you want to change the gradient at:

```
<progress data-value="0">
```

Then, in your JavaScript, check the value of the progress bar and, if it's over a value that you want to change the gradient at, update the data attribute:

```
if(progressbar1.value>=65)
    progressbar1.dataset.value=65
else if(progressbar1.value>=30)
    progressbar1.dataset.value=30
else
    progressbar1.dataset.value=0
```

Finally, in your CSS, use attribute selectors to set the rules for each value of the `data-value` attribute, changing the gradient and/or whatever other styles you want:

```
progress[data-value="0"]::-webkit-progress-value{
    background-image:/* red gradient here */;
}
progress[data-value="30"]::-webkit-progress-value{
    background-image:/* yellow gradient here */;
}
progress[data-value="65"]::-webkit-progress-value{
    background-image:/* green gradient here */;
}
```